# rbind and overwrite duplicate rows based on key variable?

Tags: r, duplicates, rbind

```
> part1<-data.frame(key=c(5,6,7,8,9),x=c("b","d","a","c","b"))
> part1
  key x
1   5 b # key==5,x==b
2   6 d
3   7 a
4   8 c
5   9 b
> part2<-data.frame(key=c(1,2,3,4,5), x=c("c","a","b","d","a"))
> part2
  key x
1   1 c
2   2 a
3   3 b
4   4 d
5   5 a # key==5,x==a
```

There are more than 2 dataframes but I'll just use 2 for this example. I then use lapply to put them all in a list called dflist1, then rbind them. For this example I'll just do it manually.

```
dflist1<-list(part1,part2)
final<-do.call(rbind,dflist1)
final<-final[order(final$key),] #sort by key
```

Result:

```
> final
   key x
6    1 c
7    2 a
8    3 b
9    4 d
1    5 b #duplicate from part1
10   5 a #duplicate from part2
2    6 d
3    7 a
4    8 c
5    9 b
```

I want to get rid of the duplicates. It's easy to use !duplicated() but in this case I specifically want to drop/overwrite the rows from earlier dataframes - i.e., in this case the "5 b" from part1 should get dropped/overwritten by the "5 a" from part2. And if there was a part3 with a value "5 b" then the "5 a" from part2 would then get dropped/overwritten by the "5 b" from part3.

What I want:

```
   key x
6    1 c
7    2 a
8    3 b
9    4 d
10   5 a #this is from part2, no more duplicate from part1
2    6 d
3    7 a
4    8 c
5    9 b
```

Current solution: The only thing I can think of is to add a function that flags each dataframe with an extra variable, then sort it and use !duplicated on that variable... is there an easier or more elegant solution that doesn't require flagging?

Comment: hint:  use `data.table(), setkey(), unique()`

Comment: Also, note that R's sort function is a [stable sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) and  preserves satellite data, so you can just reverse, use !duplicated, and reverse again.

Comment: Perhaps, "fromLast = T" argument of `duplicated` could be useful? E.g. `final[!duplicated(final$key, fromLast = T), ]` looks like your output

Answer (score 0):

```
## Create many data.frames

set.seed(1)

## Normally, do this in lapply... 
part1 <- data.frame(key=1:6,  x=sample(letters, 6))
part2 <- data.frame(key=4:8,  x=sample(letters, 5))
part3 <- data.frame(key=8:12, x=sample(letters, 5))
```

---

```
library(data.table)

## Collect all your "parts"
PARTS.LIST <- lapply(ls(pattern="^part\\d+"), function(x) get(x))


DT.part <- rbindlist(PARTS.LIST)

setkey(DT.part, key)
unique(DT.part, by="key")
```

---

```
ORIGINAL          UNIQUE
---------         -----------
> DT.part         > unique(DT.part, by="key")
    key x             key x
 1:   1 l          1:   1 l
 2:   2 v          2:   2 v
 3:   3 k          3:   3 k
 4:   4 q          4:   4 q
 5:   4 i          5:   5 r
 6:   5 r          6:   6 f
 7:   5 w          7:   7 v
 8:   6 f          8:   8 f
 9:   6 o          9:   9 j
10:   7 v         10:  10 d
11:   8 f         11:  11 g
12:   8 l         12:  12 m
13:   9 j
14:  10 d
15:  11 g
16:  12 m
```

Comment: Sorry to dredge this up, but the original poster didn't accept this answer or follow up on it.  I'm in the same situation as they are (except I'm using multiple keys) and this answer only slightly doesn't work.  I want to be able to keep the latter of the key entries, not the first one.  This works perfectly except it keeps the first key (5,r) instead of the intended one (5,w).  Is the ordering of the keys contingent on what order you rbind the different data frames?

Comment: Hi @kyles. You can post a new question and simply link to this.  (Writing from my phone here)